# ValueError: Cannot specify ',' with 's', when adding comma and set to two decimal values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

The first two columns (Total Rides and Total Drivers) came out fine.

However, the codes for the rest of the columns wouldn't work. I have tried to remove "2f" to test them out. But still wouldn't work, and received the "ValueError: Cannot specify ',' with 's'." message.

I am wondering what I did wrong or overlooked here.

---

```
pyber_summary_df ["Total Rides"] = pyber_summary_df["Total Rides"].map("{:,}".format)
pyber_summary_df ["Total Drivers"] = pyber_summary_df["Total Drivers"].map("{:,}".format)

pyber_summary_df ["Total Fares"] = pyber_summary_df ["Total Fares"].map("{:,2f}".format
pyber_summary_df ["Average Fare per Ride"] = pyber_summary_df ["Average Fare per Ride"].map("{:,2f}".format)
pyber_summary_df ["Average Fare per Driver"] = pyber_summary_df ["Average Fare per Driver"].map("{:,2f}".format)


pyber_summary_df
```

Comment: Replace `,` by `.`: `"{:.2f}"`. It's a dot not a comma

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are numeric, use [`round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) instead:

```
pyber_summary_df["Total Fares"] = pyber_summary_df["Total Fares"].round(2)
pyber_summary_df["Average Fare per Ride"] = pyber_summary_df["Average Fare per Ride"].round(2)
pyber_summary_df["Average Fare per Driver"] = pyber_summary_df["Average Fare per Driver"].round(2)
```